# Yii2 dropdownlist WITHOUT $model

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2

I have searched the web far and wide for a solution to this problem. I already know the Yii2 dropdown way is this:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\Standard;
?>

<?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 's_id',
      ArrayHelper::map(Standard::find()->all(), 's_id', 'name')) ?>
```

But I want to make the dropdown without the `$model`... Is there ANY way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can also use

`Html::dropDownList()`

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('s_id', null,
      ArrayHelper::map(Standard::find()->all(), 's_id', 'name')) ?>
```

See [Yii Manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail)

Comment: This does not work, it throws the error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given because as a parameter, I still have to pass: `Standard::find()->all()` which is still a array... how can I bypass this?

Comment: The first parameter is the name to be assigned to the control, the second the value and the the third the items.

Comment: Thanks, I had my parameters wrongly assigned! This is solved and Thank you for your quick response. Can I bother you IF I encounter anymore issues? P.S: I will accept the answer in 2 mins... That is when I reach the standard time. :D

Comment: No problem, but I cannot guarantee quick responses like this.

Comment: that is not an issue :) whenever you have time, if you have it :)

Comment: @AresDraguna There are a lot of people around that might help if he's not around

Comment: This violates MVC principles by putting code in the view.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $get = Standard::find()->all();
    $result = ArrayHelper::map($get, 'id', 'name');
    return $result;
}
```

Then dropdown:

```
<?= Html::dropDownList(Standard::getAll(), ['prompt' => '--- select ---']) ?>
```

This will solve your error.